# x11 pdf viewer right-to-left page order continuous horizontal scroll

Tags: pdf, gui

Want a pdf viewer:

- To run under x11.
- To display a file with the first page at the rightmost, then subsequent pages leftwards, to scroll horizontally without page flipping or gaps.
- To inspect [page order hinting in the pdf metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/548189/pdf-metadata-right-to-left) and render accordingly, To provide an option to explicitly select the right-to-left layout.